# EclipseLink JPA em.persist silently fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have plenty of working EJBs all correctly persisting data and then there's this one which doesn't persist to database or return any error, its only difference from other EJBs is that it @Inject two times with CDI

Jersey Resource:

```
@Path("/file")
@Stateless
public class FileResource extends Application
{
    @Inject
    private LibraryController libraryController; //getters setters omitted

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadWeb(InputStream inputStream)
    {
       getLibraryController().uploadFile();
    }
}
```

CDI Bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LibraryController implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    private FileEJBLocal fileEJB; //getters setters omitted

    uploadFile()
    {
            File rootFile = new File();
            try
            {
                getFileEJB().create(rootFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(LibraryController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
     }
}
```

EJB Bean:

```
@Stateless
public class FileEJB implements FileEJBLocal
{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public File create(File file) throws Exception
    {
        em.persist(file);
        return file;
    }
}
```

Now what's strange is that if LibraryController was not there and I called EJB Bean straight from Jersey Resource it would persists without errors.

What's even more strange is that injection works correctly and upon debugging the create(File file) method is correctly called with a not null File  object!

**EDIT:** I am closely debugging line by line and checking the mysql database with phpmyadmin to see when the file is actually persisted, what's strange is the following behaviour: if I persist a File and subsequently request it with the following code

```
        File File = new File();
        File.setUuid("fffffffffabababbaba");
        File.setId(new Long("129998"));
        try
        {  getFileEJB().create(File);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { // log error
        }
        try
        {  File FileReturned = getFileEJB().getFileById(new Long("129998"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { // log error
        }
```

the FileReturned is correctly returned but phpmyadmin shows me the database is not persisted with the file. I'm starting to think debugging and checking database concurrently is not possible, maybe the data is persisted in some buffer Table?
Maybe because I'm using a Mysql connection pool?

Any ideas?

**NOTE:** I'm using Glassfish 4.0 Jersey 2.0 and EclipseLink but this shouldn't be specific to this configuration.

Comment: You probably have an exception, written to your log file.

Comment: I debug the code line by line and it correctly executes em.persist and correctly returns. The log prints several things but nothing regarding any warning or error. Data however is not persisted.

Comment: Could it be that it never commits the transaction?

Comment: If I debug after create() is called nothing is persisted, but when LibraryController returns it sometimes persists, however I need data to be present while I am inside LibraryController class! I added an EDIT to further specify, I have no idea how to debug persistence any further.